# R-2R ladder connected to amplifier causes voltage to DECREASE

Tags: amplifier, resistors, dac, lm386, r2r

I'm working on a project and requires 4-bits of data from a micro-controller. I chose R to equal 1k ohms and the max V_out from the DAC (V_R-2R) without the amplifier measures around 1.6V and the current is about 0.8mA. When I connect the amplifier (LM386n-1 powered by a 5V source) according to a schematic below, with resistor R_f value 2k ohms,  I expect V_o to equal 3.2V. Rather my measured values are: current  is about 15mA and voltage is about 0.9V (yes it goes down). In all honesty, R_f does nothing because I get the same reading on my Voltmeter if I remove that resistor. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Your diagram shows neither an R2R ladder nor an LM386...

Comment: You do realize that an LM386 is *not an opamp* right?

Comment: In the schematic, the R-2R has been Theveninized to a single R. I also figured the amplifier in the schematic could represent any amplifier as long as the connections were made appropriately

Comment: No, it needs to be an opamp. Also, note the negative sign in the equation, you need to power the opamp with both positive and negative voltages.

Comment: @brhans @ Mattman944 https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf page 7 of the datasheet says it IS an op amp

Comment: It is a *power amplifier* with a (low) fixed gain, not the same as an opamp. Trust us, we have used these parts.

Comment: Yeah - well, that statement is *very* misleading. By all traditional definitions, it is *not* an opamp, and cannot be used as one in any circuit where a "real" opamp is specified.

Comment: Is there a schematic you would recommend using the LM386? I'm trying to use it on a speaker and, following the schematic above, it works it's just super low.

Comment: what speaker impedance?

Comment: It's an 8 ohms speaker

Comment: You were misled by the word Op Amp.  The gain here is 20 to 200 not 1e5 to 1e7.. The 1st paragraph describes it best. **The LM386 is a mono low voltage** (audio) **amplifier**. Is this for DC power control or what?

Comment: WEll it was an Op Amp until they made it simpler to use by adding 20 to 200 gain limiting resistors for a speaker driver, but you won't get rail to rail.

Comment: Are you trying to design a digital gain control? for audio to 8 ohms? hmm

Comment: I'm trying to amplify the audio coming from my speaker

Comment: You mean going to your speaker.. Then just use the fixed 20x gain and reduce input elsewhere and use massive e-cap coupling for bass. >=250uF  see fig 10 . do that

Comment: Thanks. I followed the schematic in Fig. 12 and it was still a bit low but definitely audible

Answer (score 1):

Put the amplifier after the resistor DAC. R6 needs to attenuate enough to account for the minimum gain of the LM386 (20). Larger value resistors might be better, 10X what I specified. You will need to experiment with R6 to get the proper output level, it is too high as shown.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f61wyP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For an input of 1.6V you shouldn't have expected an output of 3.2V, you should have expected an output of -3.2V (note the minus sign in your equation).

I suspect you're not seeing a negative voltage because your opamp does not have a negative rail.

If the negative power pin of the opamp is at ground (instead of a negative voltage) then the opamp will go as low as it can, which is probably 0.9V.

It will stay at 0.9V if you remove Rf because the negative input is higher (1.6V) than the positive input (0V).

Comment: Actually I was seeing a (-) sometimes. I just ignored it because I knew I had it connected to the negative pin of the LM386

Comment: There's no op-amp in the asker's actual circuit.  The depicted diagram is false.

Comment: Indeed. LM386 is not an op-amp, it has maximum input amplitude of +/- 400mV, and since minimum gain is 20,  the max input is limited to much less than that, unless LM386 supply voltage is more than 8V. And supply voltage is 5V so max input is really below 250mV.

Comment: How did you calculate that?